# Gmail desktop notifications with browser closed on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, gmail, notifications

Is there any way to receive Gmail desktop notifications with my browser closed on Mac OS X? I want to receive notifications like GTalk for Windows.

Comment: Hm.. If your browser is closed, you can't receive web notifications, any other functionality is not desirable in the Web Notifications API, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole bunch.

Google has it's official [Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_mac.html). Others include [Notify](http://vibealicious.com/apps/notify/), Googles official GMail [Dashboard Widget](http://www.google.com/macwidgets/index.html), [Gmail Notifr](http://ashchan.com/projects/gmail-notifr) and many more.

Comment: The URL for Dashboard Widget is now 404.  I can't find the source for the life of me...